# Errors running Fig, pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, fig

I downloaded fig but when I run it, I get this error:

```
 File "/usr/local/bin/fig", line 5, in <module>
   from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python    /pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
   needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python    /pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six>=1.3.0,<2
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a dependency. Have you checked the installation documentation? Also, did you perhaps install with Python3 as default rather than 2? If so, fix this and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!

I installed Python packages using both pip and easy_install.  I just had to use easy_install and install every one of the packages it said it was missing.

```
sudo easy_install six
sudo easy_install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use either

```
pip install fig
```

or if you have the source repo

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```